# Use of mysql_query for variable declaration

Tags: php

In the following PHP code, `s_at` is a column that includes integer values in database. I need to declare one of that value where index is 1, to `$s_at`. But won't happen in this way. I'm glad if anyone could help.

```
$s_at  = mysql_query("Select('s_at') FROM `time_holder` WHERE `index` = 1");
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they have been deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this and it will work for sure  :

```
$result = mysql_query("Select `s_at` FROM `time_holder` WHERE `index` = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$s_at = $row['s_at'];
```

Answer (score 2):

quite easy:

```
$mi_resource = mysql_query("Select `s_at` FROM `time_holder` WHERE `index` = 1");
// .... error checking left out

$records = mysql_fetch_assoc($mi_resource);
// .... error checking left out

$s_at = $records[$record_num]['s_at']; // probably #0 if only one record.

...
```

see [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: why did u use $record_num?

Comment: Just an example. Assumed, a query returns 523 records, you might want to have a loop around that then. Having queries which are returning only 1 row is quite an exception in a real database world.